# Xamarin Android Native/Forms build success but deployment failed on both emulator/device in Windows 10

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I tired xamarin native android and forms but both does seems to work. Both gives errors.

Tried creating blank xamarin android app without any code written in it, tired with xamarin forms app. Did a build, rebuild, clean, restarted system, restarted visual studio, running vs as admin all possible things but nothing worked out.

**Below is the Device Log Information**

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
10-13 23:18:30.003  Motorola XT1068 Error   19565   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime!
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4769)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4709)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1415)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
10-13 23:18:30.003  Motorola XT1068 Error   19565   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: android.content.pm.PackageManager$NameNotFoundException: Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getApplicationInfo(ApplicationPackageManager.java:304)
    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:41)
    ... 11 more

Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
10-13 23:18:30.003  Motorola XT1068 Error   19565   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find application Mono.Android.DebugRuntime!
    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:47)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5174)
    ... 10 more
```

**Below is the Output information**

```
2>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2>Done building project "demoapp.csproj".
2>Build succeeded.
2>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
2>
2>Deploy failed on Motorola XT1068
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**System Information:**

Windows 10 Operating System

Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 
Version 15.4.0

VisualStudio.15.Release/15.4.0+27004.2002
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

Xamarin   4.7.10.22 
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.

Xamarin.Android SDK   8.0.0.33
Xamarin.Android Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK   11.2.0.8 
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac Reference Assemblies and MSBuild support.

After changing to x86 and to release mode, now able to run in emulator. Below is the image.[image]

But still not able to run on Android Devices

**Edited**

**Android csproj file contents**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SelectedDevice>Motorola XT1068</SelectedDevice>
    <DefaultDevice>5" KitKat %284.4%29 XXHDPI Phone</DefaultDevice>
    <AndroidDesignerPreferredDevice>Nexus 4</AndroidDesignerPreferredDevice>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**Android Project Properties**

[image]

Comment: Can you please include your project settings? It shows you have a `Release` configuration active when it's also looking for the debug runtime. Typically `Release` configurations do not have debugging enabled nor a shared runtime to debug quicker with.

Comment: Now i am able to run in debug mode but only in emulator.. Still not able to run the apps on Devices gives the same error shown above in the post...

Comment: @JonDouglas project settings can you tell me where is it ?
so that I can share it

Comment: You should be running a debug app as "Debug - Any CPU". Secondly the project settings should be found in your .csproj file or right clicking your project and hitting `properties`. Please ensure Shared Runtime is enabled and try to deploy to your device again.

Comment: @JonDouglas I tried it earlier with all combinations and also ensuring enabling and disabling Shared Runtime but nothing works.. 
I have provided .csproj file contents and properties of android project snapshot in the post....

Comment: check your target SDK if you are compiling agaisnt API 26 you should make sure that the support libraries match the API level else you can downgrade to target API 25 and use version 25 of the android support libraries. I had the same issue and i fixed it that way. hope this help

Comment: Well now its works, seriously I didn't make any changes in the settings.. now works on emulator and device

Comment: I forgot to use MainLauncher = true that solved it.